# ロリポップサーバーにデプロイした内容が閲覧できません

Tags: dns, ipアドレス

以下のサイトを参考に、ローカルからロリポップサーバーのサブドメインへ、Laravelプロジェクトをデプロイしました。
https://vtorica.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/11/20/220222

その後、以下の操作を行いました。
①ロリポップDNSを、ドメインを取得したムームードメインで許可
②ロリポップの独自ドメインのIPアドレスの疎通をムームードメインで許可

①、②を行った後サブドメインにアクセスしましたが、画像のように 403 Error になってしまいサイトの閲覧ができません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Laravelのプロジェクトに対してローカルで行う操作と、デプロイしてからの設定は問題なく完了していることが確認できましたので、サーバーの設定に問題があると考えております。

ご面倒ながら、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: まずはDNSがきちんと設定されているか、アクセスが来ているか確認してみてください。ログにはアクセスは記録されていますか？

Comment: ロリポップ側のWAF設定を見直すと解決するかもしれないです。以前知り合いが同じような状況になった際、WAFの設定の見直しでうまくいったようです。そのときはHTMLファイルでしたが。

Comment: どちらも、試みましたが結局原因は、リポジトリに.htaccessファイルがないことでした。
.htaccessファイルを追加することで、問題なくサイトが表示されました。